# How to efficiently convert a few bytes into an integer between a range?

Tags: math, integer

I'm writing something that reads bytes (just a `List<int>`) from a remote random number generation source that is extremely slow. For that and my personal requirements, I want to retrieve **as few bytes from the source as possible**.

Now I am trying to implement a method which signature looks like:

```
int getRandomInteger(int min, int max)
```

I have two theories how I can fetch bytes from my random source, and convert them to an integer.

Approach #1 is naivé . Fetch `(max - min) / 256` number of bytes and add them up. It works, but it's going to fetch a lot of bytes from the slow random number generator source I have. For example, if I want to get a random integer between a million and a zero, it's going to fetch almost 4000 bytes... that's unacceptable.

Approach #2 sounds ideal to me, but I'm unable come up with the algorithm. it goes like this:

Lets take min: 0, max: 1000 as an example.

- Calculate `ceil(rangeSize / 256)` which in this case is `ceil(1000 / 256) = 4`. Now fetch one (1) byte from the source.
- Scale this one byte from the 0-255 range to 0-3 range (or 1-4) and let it determine which group we use. E.g. if the byte was 250, we would choose the 4th group (which represents the last 250 numbers, 750-1000 in our range).
- Now fetch another byte and scale from 0-255 to 0-250 and let that determine the position within the group we have. So if this second byte is e.g. 120, then our final integer is `750 + 120 = 870`.

In that scenario we only needed to fetch 2 bytes in total. However, it's much more complex as if our range is 0-1000000 we need several "groups".

How do I implement something like this? I'm okay with Java/C#/JavaScript code or pseudo code.

I'd also like to keep the result from not losing entropy/randomness. So, I'm slightly worried of scaling integers.

Comment: Why not take the logaritm, btw? You loose some granularity, but hey, it's random anyway.

Comment: All you need to get a random number between -2billion and +2 billion is 4 bytes. Grab 4, compose an int, do modulo range size, and add the lower bound.

Comment: Btw, if you're reading bytes, then you should probably use a `List<unsigned char>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your Approach #1 is broken. For example if min is 0 and max 510, you'd add 2 bytes.  There is only one way to get a 0 result: both bytes zero.  The chance of this is (1/256)^2.  However there are many ways to get other values, say 100 = 100+0, 99+1, 98+2... So the chance of a 100 is much larger: 101(1/256)^2.

The more-or-less standard way to do what you want is to:

```
Let R = max - min + 1   -- the number of possible random output values
Let N = 2^k >= mR, m>=1  -- a power of 2 at least as big as some multiple of R that you choose.
loop
   b = a random integer in 0..N-1 formed from k random bits
while b >= mR -- reject b values that would bias the output
return min + floor(b/m)
```

This is called the method of rejection.  It throws away randomly selected binary numbers that would bias the output. If `min-max+1` happens to be a power of 2, then you'll have zero rejections.

If you have `m=1` and `min-max+1` is just one more than a biggish power of 2, then rejections will be near half.  In this case you'd definitely want bigger `m`.

In general, bigger m values lead to fewer rejections, but of course they require slighly more bits per number. There is a probabilitistically optimal algorithm to pick `m`.

Some of the other solutions presented here have problems, but I'm sorry right now I don't have time to comment.  Maybe in a couple of days if there is interest.

Comment: Interesting. Could you perhaps show me more detailed version in C#/Java for instance? I'm not quite understanding those `m>=1` and the "bigger picture". And yes, you are absolutely right about mis-balanced chances for some integer values.

Answer (score 1):

3 bytes (together) give you random integer in range 0..16777215. You can use 20 bits from this value to get range 0..1048575 and throw away values > 1000000

Answer (score 1):

```
range 1 to r
256^a >= r

first find 'a' 

get 'a' number of bytes into array A[]

num=0
for i=0 to len(A)-1
    num+=(A[i]^(8*i))
next

random number = num mod range
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `mod` kills randomness/entropy quality, because the values in the beginning are more likely to occur if you use `mod`?

Comment: @Tower :i didn't know that,sorry i wasn't able to help

Answer (score 1):

Your random source gives you 8 random bits per call. For an integer in the range [min,max] you would need ceil(log2(max-min+1)) bits.

Assume that you can get random bytes from the source using some function:

```cpp
bool RandomBuf(BYTE* pBuf , size_t nLen); // fill buffer with nLen random bytes
```

Now you can use the following function to generate a random value in a given range:

```cpp
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// produce a uniformly-distributed integral value in range [nMin, nMax]
// T is char/BYTE/short/WORD/int/UINT/LONGLONG/ULONGLONG
template <class T> T RandU(T nMin, T nMax)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, "RandU: integral type expected");

    if (nMin>nMax)
        std::swap(nMin, nMax);

    if (0 == (T)(nMax-nMin+1)) // all range of type T
    {
        T nR;
        return RandomBuf((BYTE*)&nR, sizeof(T)) ? *(T*)&nR : nMin;
    }

    ULONGLONG nRange    = (ULONGLONG)nMax-(ULONGLONG)nMin+1        ; // number of discrete values
    UINT      nRangeBits= (UINT)ceil(log((double)nRange) / log(2.)); // bits for storing nRange discrete values
    ULONGLONG nR                                                   ;

    do
    {
        if (!RandomBuf((BYTE*)&nR, sizeof(nR)))
            return nMin;

        nR= nR>>((sizeof(nR)<<3) - nRangeBits); // keep nRangeBits random bits
    }
    while (nR >= nRange);                       // ensure value in range [0..nRange-1]

    return nMin + (T)nR;                        // [nMin..nMax]
}
```

Since you are always getting a multiple of 8 bits, you can save extra bits between calls  (for example you may need only 9 bits out of 16 bits). It requires some bit-manipulations, and it is up to you do decide if it is worth the effort.

You can save even more, if you'll use 'half bits': Let's assume that you want to generate numbers in the range [1..5]. You'll need log2(5)=2.32 bits for each random value. Using 32 random bits you can actually generate floor(32/2.32)= 13 random values in this range, though it requires some additional effort.

Comment: Hmm that is a good point, although my random source always returns full bytes. :) let me see if I can adapt your implementation.