# How to generate a random number with equal probability in a given interval

Tags: algorithm, random

I tried a lot but could not get a solution for this problem

> Function returns numbers in range `[1,6]` with equal probability. You can use library's `rand()` function and you can assume  implementation of `rand()` returns number in range number in range `[0,RAND_MAX]` with equal probability.

Comment: What is your best thought on how to solve this ?  Convince us that you have indeed tried a lot.

Comment: Define "number". Should it be able to return 1.5? pi? sqrt(2)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008804/generating-random-integer-from-a-range/5009307#5009307

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323790/how-to-efficiently-convert-a-few-bytes-into-an-integer-between-a-range/13323903#13323903

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We'll do this in multiple steps.

You need to generate a number in the range `[1, 6]`, inclusive.

You have a random number generator that will generate numbers in the range `[0..RAND_MAX]`.

Let's say you wanted to generate numbers in the range `[0..5]`. You can do this:

```
int r = rand();  // gives you a number from 0 to RAND_MAX
double d = r / RAND_MAX;  // gives you a number from 0 to 1
double val = d * 5; // gives you a number from 0 to 5
int result = round(d);  // rounds to an integer
```

You can use that technique to So given a range of `[0, high]`, you can generate a random number, divide by `RAND_MAX`, multiply by `high`, and round the result.

Your range is `[1, 6]`, so you have to add another step. You want to generate a random number in the range `[0, 5]`, and then add 1. Or, in general, to generate a random number in a given range, `[low, high]`, you write:

```
int r = rand();
double d = r / RAND_MAX;
int range = high - low + 1;
double val = d * range;
result = round(val);
```

Obviously you can combine some of those operations. I just showed them individually to illustrate.

Comment: Note that from pigeon hole principle - this will suffer from the same bias issue as `rand() % 6 + 1`, you are going to spread `MAX_RAND` numbers (pigeons) to 6 integers (pigeon holes) - this will result in one of the holes at least have `ceil(RAND_MAX/6)`, and assuming RAND_MAX%6 != 0 - it will be biased. Nevertheless - elegant!

Comment: @amit you are correct . we should bind r in [1,rand_num],such that rand_num is closest to RAND_MAX and rand_num%6=0.

Comment: @Nik-Lz Dividing by `RAND_MAX` gives you a number in the range [0..1) (greater than or equal to 0, and less than 1.0). This will give a slightly skewed probability if `RAND_MAX%6 != 0`, as noted in the first comment. See the second comment for how to fix that.

Comment: @Nik-Lz We have to assume that `rand()` is returning numbers with equal probability. All we do is map those numbers to the given range, maintaining that probability. If you can't depend on `rand()` to do the right thing, then we'd have to write our own pseudo random number generator. That clearly wasn't part of the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you are looking for using the `operator%` (modolus).

> r = rand() % 6 + 1

If you are afraid that `RAND_MAX % 6 != 0` and the solution will be biased - you just need to 'throw' some numbers (up to 5) out and redraw if you get them:

```
let M = (RAND_MAX / 6) * 6 [integer division]
r = dontCare
do { 
   r = rand()
} while (r > M)
r = r % 6 + 1
```

---

PS, if you want to draw a 'real' number, it can be done with:

```
r = drawInt(1,5) // draw integer from 1 to 5 inclusive, as previously explained.
r += rand() / (RAND_MAX - 1) //the decimal part
```

Note that it is not a 'real' number, and the density between two numbers is `1/RAND_MAX-1`

Comment: it is wrong ... think !! it will not give with equal probability ... check for rand_max=13

Comment: @user3187111 Have you actually read the answer before commenting? the second part of the answer, specifically? It deals with it exactly.

Comment: it is inefficient too.Sorry!