# Generate number with equal probability

Tags: algorithm, probability

You are given a function let’s say bin() which will generate 0 or 1 with equal probability. Now you are given a range of contiguous integers say [a,b] (a and b inclusive).

Write a function say rand() using bin() to generate numbers within range [a,b] with equal probability

Comment: what do you know about a and b? what have you tried?

Comment: I tried   [(b-a+1)*bin()]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The insight you need is that your `bin()` function returns a single binary digit, or "bit". Invoking it once gives you 0 or 1. If you invoke it twice you get two bits `b0` and `b1` which can be combined as `b1 * 2 + b0`, giving you one of 0, 1, 2 or 3 with equal probability. If you invoke it thrice you get three bits `b0`, `b1` and `b2`. Put them together and you get `b2 * 2^2 + b1 * 2 + b0`, giving you a member of {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} with equal probability. And so on, as many as you want.

Your range [a, b] has `m = b-a+1` values. You just need enough bits to generate a number between 0 and `2^n-1`, where `n` is the smallest value that makes `2^n-1` greater than or equal to `m`. Then just scale that set to start at `a` and you're good.

So let's say you are given the range [20, 30]. There are 11 numbers there from 20 to 30 inclusive. 11 is greater than 8 (2^3), but less than 16 (2^4), so you'll need 4 bits. Use `bin()` to generate four bits `b0`, `b1`, `b2`, and `b3`. Put them together as `x = b3 * 2^3 + b2 * 2^2 + b1 * 2 + b0`. You'll get a result, `x`, between 0 and 15. If x > 11 then generate another four bits. When x <= 11, your answer is `x + 20`.

Answer (score 2):

Help, but no code:

- You can shift the range [0,2 ** n] easily to [a,a+2 ** n]
- You can easily produce an equal probability from [0,2**n-1]
- If you need a number that isn't a power of 2, just generate a number up to 2 ** n and re-roll if it exceeds the number you need

Comment: Carlos :I could not understand your logic    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119930/how-to-generate-a-random-number-with-equal-probability-in-a-given-interval

Comment: Can you please explain your logic

Comment: @geeky what do you not understand? Say you want a number from 0 to 5. Generate a number from 0 to 7. If it's 6 or 7, do it until again. For a number from 25 to 30, just add 25 to the result.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the numbers to work out your range:

```
Decimal: 20 - 10 = 10
Binary : 10100 - 01010 = 1010
```

Work out how many bits you need to represent this: `4`.

For each of these, generate a random 1 or 0:

```
num_bits = 4
rand[num_bits]
for (x = 0; x < num_bits; ++x)
  rand[x] = bin()
```

Let's say rand[] = `[0,1,0,0]` after this. Add this number back to the start of your range.

```
Binary: 1010 + 0100 = 1110
Decimal: 10 + 4 = 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the range [a,b] to [0,b-a], denote X = b - a. Then you can define a function rand(X) as follows:

```
function int rand(X){
   int i = 1;
   // determine how many bits you need (see above answer for why)
   while (X < 2^i) {
      i++;
   }
   // generate the random numbers
   Boolean cont = true;
   int num = 0;
   while (cont == true) {
      for (j = 1 to i) {
         // this generates num in range [0,2^i -1] with equal prob
         // but we need to discard if num is larger than X
         num = num + bin() * 2^j;
      }
      if (num <= X) { cont = false}
   }
   return num;
}
```